# How fine it is to use "use database " statement in a transaction ( BEGIN TRAN ), Are there any potential adverse implications?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

There might be large no of records to be updated.I tried in a small DB but there was no problem for small set of records. running a statement like below.

```
BEGIN TRAN 

use db1 
update .....
update .... 
update ...
.
.
.
.
.
COMMIT
```

Comment: Safest to put the use outside of the `TRAN`. Will you be accessing more then one DB?

Comment: Right now I am using only one DB but  I am trying to understand possible cases where this style might be trouble.

Comment: What are you expecting as an answer here? This is so vague.

Comment: Also, a transaction can only apply to one DB as far as I am aware.

Comment: I would fully qualify the DB e.g. update DatabaseName.dbo.TableName instead of trying to juggle the use command.